# Jquery html attr radio input alt content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use Jquery Attr.Radio Button click and write to #RadioDesc id's div...

```
<input type="radio" desc="sample description" class="AddText">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $("radio").click( function() {
            $("#RadioDesc").attr("desc");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="RadioDesc"></div>
```

These codes not work...Please help me solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your selector is invalid, change:

```
$("radio").click(function(){
```

to

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
        $(":radio").click( function() {
            //add to html
            $("#RadioDesc").html($(this).attr("desc"));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks your code...This is working ok...but another radio button same radio empty desc and click div content is not remove How do I make it ?

Comment: +1 .. I am new to JQuery pls can u tell me how is selector `radio` different from `:radio` ?

Comment: @user2637668 do you mean you have another radio button which does not have desc attribute and on clicking it you want to remove the content of div ..? or could you clear what you exactly want to do..?

Comment: @Che there's no such selector as $('radio').. you need to use $('[type=radio]'), or $('input:radio').. or other formats which you can check in jquery docs

Comment: @Sudhir yes, I have another radio button which does not have desc attribute and on clicking it I want to remove the content of div...

Comment: @user2637668 the code should work for what you mentioned as well.. see:: http://jsfiddle.net/4KnxP/

Comment: @Sudhir many thanks for help...Yes the code should work My problem is PHP code if empty : ) Solved the problem...Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Html:

```
<input type="radio" desc="sample description" class="AddText">
<div id="RadioDesc"></div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
           $("#RadioDesc").text($(this).attr("desc"));
        });});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECYGP/)

Answer (score 1):

The radio selector is [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":radio").click(function () {
        $("#RadioDesc").html($(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't targeting the radio, its targeting an element radio

try this:

```
$('input[type=radio]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change div's html to radio's attribute value

```
<input type="radio" desc="sample description" class="AddText">
<div id="RadioDesc"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $("input:radio").click( function() {
            $("#RadioDesc").html( $(this).attr("desc") );
        });
    });
</script>
```